# Java SWT no automatic cursor change after manuel cursor change

Tags: java, cursor, swt

I am working on a large Project for 2 months and I have got an annoying Problem I cant resolve: I am using setCursor(..) to change the Mouse Cursor, why is not important. After I set the cursor back to the original it wont change automatically again. Mouse hoover over a text editing field usually changes the cursor, and I want that to happen just like before I set the Cursor manually, but it dos not.

here is my (relevant) code:

```
if(condition)
                shlell.setCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_CROSS));
            else
                shellsetCursor(new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: So what is the behavior that you want? There is a `Widget` for which you want to change the `Cursor`?

Answer (score 3):

You should not create system cursors, but rather reuse the existing ones:

```
shell.setCursor(display.getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
```

To reset to the control's default cursor, unset it:

```
shell.setCursor(null);
```